# Ui element and knockout js array subscriber/listener

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I would like to do 2 thinks with knockout js and UI component

1. Fill in input in a grid based on entity_id - Works great
2. Trigger callback when one of input has changed

The second part works partly. When I am using **collectionDates** as string then all of the input will get same value and when one of the input are changed then **valueChanged** method is called.

When **collectionDates** is set as an array (so that every input can have it's own value) then the callback wont trigger when any of inputs value change. Reading knockout js documentation for [observable arrays](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) I believe this should be possible. Why magento 2 UI component does not track changes of array elements?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column'
], function ($, Column) {
    'use strict';

    return Column.extend({
        defaults: {
            collectionDates: {
                19: 100,
                21: 200
            },
            listens:{
                collectionDates: 'valueChanged'
            }
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            return this._super()
                .track(['collectionDates']);
        },
        valueChanged: function (val, val2, val3) {
            debugger
        }
    });
});
```

Template used for input

```
<input
    type="text"
    data-bind="value: collectionDates[$row().entity_id]"
/>
```

Comment: So far I have found that I could use `event: {change: valueChanged}` in **data-bind**. Still this does not feel right. I am staring to wonder if this is some kind of a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I researched this topic for 2 day and found that it isn't that simple. This could be done but needs custom bindings. Something similar to **staticChecked** binding found in multi select column component (ui/grid/cells/multiselect). 
 
 
  Binding itself is located here

```
C:\Users\Pisikoll\Documents\drive-innMagento\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\lib\knockout\bindings\staticChecked.js
```

For now without writing complicated code events are the way to go.